# Loop through multiple SQL statements and store the results in Python object

Tags: python, sql, loops

I have a text file that has about 100 DB table names in it separated by a new line, and I have a function to return those table names in a list here:

```
def grab_tables(self):
    table_list = []
    with open('tables.txt', 'r') as file:
        datalines = (line.rstrip('\r\n') for line in file)
        for line in datalines:
            table_list.append(line)
    return table_list
```

I now want to connect to the DB and do a select count(*) on all those tables and store the table name and counts in some python object (list, dictionary, whatever).  What I have so far is this:

```
def run_sql(self):
    s = self.connection_src() #function that connects to Oracle DB
    tables = self.grab_tables()
    a = s.cursor()
    z = []
    for table in tables:            
        a.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM {}'.format(table))
        z.append(a)

    print(z)
```

This is not working though, as it is appending the connection details to z. Clearly incorrect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't really about looping through multiple SQL statements at all. The question is how to get the result from a call to `execute`.

The answer to that is to call `fetchone()` on the cursor. This will give you a tuple, so get the first element of that:

```
a.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM {}'.format(table))
z.append(a.fetchone()[0])
```

Comment: thank you Daniel.  that worked great.  Silly question, how would I then add the table name next to the result?  The above returns the results which is great, but I want to associate it with the table as well

Comment: You could append a tuple of `(table, a.fetchone..)` fur example. Or make z a dict where the key is the table name.

Comment: thanks, i was just going to reply that I had figured it out using list comprehension.  Thanks again